# How to use createStackNavigator in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

**My current code**

App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import AuthenticationNavigator from 'app/src/navigations/AuthenticationNavigator';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AuthenticationNavigator />;
  }
}
```

AuthenticationNavigator.js

```js
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
onst AuthenticationNavigator = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Loading: { screen: LoadingScreen },
        Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Loading',
    },
  ),
);
export default AuthenticationNavigator;
```

I changed AuthenticationNavigator.js to

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
const AuthenticationNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
      Loading: { screen: LoadingScreen },
      Login: { screen: LoginScreen },
  },
  {
      initialRouteName: 'Loading',
  },
);

export default AuthenticationNavigator;
```

I wanna use createStackNavigator instead of using createSwitchNavigator.

I'm facing

> Error: Creating a navigator doesn't take an argument. Maybe you are trying to use React Navigation 4 API with React Navigation 5?

**package.json**

```js
{
  "name": "app",
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.18",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.1.1",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
  },
  "private": true
}
```

There are 2 different react-navigation-stack.
Does this bring the error?

I would appreciate it if you could give me any advices :)

Comment: Currently you have mixed up reactnavigation version 4 and version 5. Can you please specify which version you want to use ?

Comment: Ok. I will add answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have mixed up reactnavigation version 4 and version 5.

```js
import { createSwitchNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
```

is a part of reactnavigation version 4. And

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

is a part of reactnavigation version 5. So If you want to use v5 then first, install reactnavigation using :

> npm install @react-navigation/native

then, install rest of dependencies by following [this](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) guide. Now, install stackNavigator using command :

> npm install @react-navigation/stack

More detail is [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/hello-react-navigation).

Now, you can create navigation as below :

```js
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import Loading from './containers/Loading';
import Login from './containers/Login';

const {Navigator, Screen} = createStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => (
  <Navigator headerMode="none">
    <Screen name="Loading" component={Loading} />
    <Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
  </Navigator>
);

const AppNavigator = () => (
  <NavigationContainer>
    <AuthStack />
  </NavigationContainer>
);

export default AuthenticationNavigator;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Now I'm facing a new error > This navigator has both navigation and container props, so it is unclear if it should own its own state. Remove props: "route" if the navigator should get its state from the navigation prop. If the navigator should maintain its own state, do not pass a navigation prop.

Comment: Sorry, but I am not able to understand the your error. Can you please post screenshot ?

Comment: Sorry It worked! Thank you so much. Also, I want to use createBottomTabNavigator, so I'm going to post another question. I would appreciate it if you could check it too.

Comment: Help me with this issue if you can? Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61606346/react-navigation-v5-pass-function-as-parameter-to-be-used-in-headerright-butto

Comment: Heyy @newdeveloper I posted my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't have an argument for creating stack navigator. For example:

```
const AuthenticationStack = createStackNavigator();

const AuthenticationStackNavigator = () => {
    return(
        <AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
            <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="login" component = {Login}/>
            <AuthenticationStack.Screen name="register" component = {Register} />
        </AuthenticationStack.Navigator>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the navigators wrong way, in react navigation V5 you create navigators differently from V4, please go through the stack navigator [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) for more details